# Youtube API - stream key issue - lives stream

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, live-streaming

We have a project where we create slots for the live stream. Project has been created on the Google cloud platform, implemented the oauth2.0 connection. It worked well at first, but we wanted to switch from testing mode to production. We have not received stream keys back since then, so we cannot use our tool. According to the dashboard the tool connects to the project. We tried to get back from production to test mode but it did not help. We started the process from the scratch, but the result is the same: no stream keys (we get back an empty string). Any advice? Maybe due to the change to the production mode, do we have to go through the verification procedure to get stream key? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to get your application audited and approved by Google.

Fill in [this form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en); then wait for their response.

Be aware that, according to the experience of users of this forum, Google's answer does not come shortly.